# When would an informative __repr__ be dangerous?

Tags: python, repr

I am having trouble understanding why the default `__repr__`'s implementation isn't more informative.

This answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/3646408 
states

> having a default for **repr** which would act like:  `return "%s(%r)"
>   % (self.__class__, self.__dict__)`  would have been too dangerous (for
>   example, too easy to get into infinite recursion if objects reference
>   each other).

Such case would be

```
instance = Class(); instance.attr = instance
```

This seems like more a mistake to me. What could be a valid use-case where this could happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a valid use case for some hierarchical structure, when node can have children that reference their parent

As an example,

```
root = Node()
child = Node()
child.parent=root
root.children = [child]
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider a [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) tree where a node contains references to its children, and every child contains a reference to its parent.

(It also happens between siblings via `nextSibling`/`previousSibling`.)

Answer (score 2):

This could happen with any type of object with bidirectional references. For instance, a class that represents family relationships, where each person has a reference to their spouse, or where parents have references to their children and children have references to their parents.

PHP's `print_r()` does what you suggest; see [Recursion using PHP Simple DOM Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37627214/recursion-using-php-simple-dom-parser/37627269#37627269) for the problem someone had trying to print the object that represents an HTML DOM element.